# Will AFK fishing overheat my computer?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am playing on a server with my friends and one of said he uses an AFK fish farm to get fish and lots of loot. Recently, I died three times over the weekend for fooling around and not concentrating. I can get my xp back with a mob xp farm, and my valuable items back because I'm a rich player.

But, I found it hard getting my enchantments back, so I decided to build an AFK fisher in a private world and test it for 2 hours. It worked and was quite successful. But, by the end of it my 2010 Mac Book Pro was extremely warm and was making that hissing sound, to cool it off.

Will my computer fry itself or burn something if I leave it for around 9 hours overnight with a weight on the spacebar so my fish farm will work?

Comment: Also, what does AFK even stand for and please post other cool AFK tutorials and machines that I could use if you know any, in the comments, thx!

Comment: If your mac overheat after 2 hours, quite sure it won't get any better after 9 hours...

Comment: AFK stands for _Away From Keyboard_.  People say "I'm going AFK" when they are physically leaving the computer/console to go do something else (usually quick).

Comment: I think you should not make self-catching farm, I would consider it cheating, if you made one on my server and let the computer do it for you without you really playing. If you want exp, the fastest is to build some proper mob trap, especially endertrap is kinda fast, if built right. But bot-fishing? Nope.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about exploiting the game.

Comment: @dly it's not cheating. Cheating is using commands, and anything you can do in vanilla Minecraft without using glitches is not cheating or exploiting.

Comment: @RudolfL.Jelínek being afk means you're away from keyboard and not placing stuff on it to endlessly run the game and even do stuff automatically. That's not how the game is designed = exploiting in-game mechanics.

Comment: @dly And even if one could consider this exploiting, it is still allowed. And it's up to the server owners to decide whether they allow this, so this question can't be closed as multiplayer cheating until the OP tells us what server he's playing on, and what are the rules on it.

Comment: This is not about server rules. Only the definition matters.

Comment: @dly Playing the game in an unintended way isn't a valid close reason. I agree with the close as off topic though, as asking whether something will cause a computer to overheat isn't something we can really answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To lower the weight that minecraft lasts on your computer you could try to set the fps limit in the video settings of minecraft on 10 fps, cause fps is just your gaming experience. And if you are fishing on a server the server controls if the fish comes to you or not! So yeah just try to lower as much as possible settings. If that does not work you could try a CPU/GPU/RAM limo program so minecraft wouldn't suck up your whole MacBook that it starts to cool!